# armv7 is successful but compile for arm64 throws Implicit Function declaration error

Tags: ios, macos, armv7, arm64

Have to compile security library (create static library) for IOS.

Below is the makefile snippet:

```
SDK_ROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk
#CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc
CC=llvm-gcc
TARGET=security
ARCH=arm64
```

Now on changing the ARCH=armv7, compilation is successful but for ARCH=arm64

Compiling the same code gives error as below:
crypto.c:580:18: error: implicit declaration of function 'aes_hardware_cbc' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

The above error can be resolved on adding declaration of the function in header file

But I wanted to know how architecture changes brings on Implicit Function Declaration errors or , change warning to errors.

Machine Details:
MAC OS: 10.11 EL Captain
Iphone SDK: iPhoneOS9.0.sdk
Compiler: llvm-gcc (/usr/bin)

Comment: which .h file is "`aes_hardware_cbc`" really defined at, at least in the "`armv7`" case?  Also, is this a public security library that I can see (e.g. on GitHub?)

Comment: aes_hardware_cbc is not declared in any .h file. It is defined in crypto.c file and called from other *.c files.  This is  an open source security library for SSL encryption.